# start motion on click?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm having a problem with a small animation for a form I'm creating in flash. Basically I want the motion to happen when I click it, and then stop where its told to. It plays and stops just fine, however I cannot figure out how to make it wait for the click to play. This is the current code I have

```
tabbut.onClick = function() { play(); }
```

i have also tried the MouseEvent method, but that makes it keep looping.

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have also tried the MouseEvent
>   method, but that makes it keep
>   looping.

This is the correct approach. `play()` will play *and loop*. If you need finer control on the playback, I suggest adding a listener to `enterframe` event and doing the required logic there.

```
    // Play when clicked
myMovieClip.addEventListener("click", function(event:MouseEvent) {
    play();
});
    // Stop when arrived on last frame
    // This could be replaced by inline frame code on the last frame
myMovieClip.addEventListener("enterframe", function(event:Event) {
    if(currentFrame == totalFrames)
        stop();
});
```

Comment: thank you for your advice! the animation still automatically plays when the form is loaded, but now when it stops i can click on it and it replays.
i need the movement to not start UNTIL it is clicked.

Comment: OH i fixed it. I forgot to add the stop action in the first frame >.< thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the main timeline, you need to put a `stop();` action on the first frame.

If your animation is inside a MovieClip (which is recommended), then use the following:

```
myClip.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

have implemented your animation with code or in a movie clip timeline? if you have a movie clip timeline, insert a stop(); statement in the first frame of the movie clip code.